# Logon failed for login <<user name>> due to trigger execution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following issue for a SQL Server 2016 instance.

Usually everything works fine but form time to time we are getting Error 17892 followed by error 18056. This is a selection form the error log of the instance:

```
2019-03-20 16:38:19.90 Logon       Login succeeded for user <<User Name 1>>. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENT: 10.xxx.xxx.xxx]
2019-03-20 16:38:40.96 Logon       Error: 17892, Severity: 20, State: 1.
2019-03-20 16:38:40.96 Logon       Logon failed for login <<User Name 1>> due to trigger execution. [CLIENT: 10.xxx.xxx.xxx]
2019-03-20 16:38:40.96 spid76      Error: 18056, Severity: 20, State: 1.
2019-03-20 16:38:40.96 spid76      The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 76, which had been reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 1. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.
2019-03-20 16:38:45.36 Logon       Error: 17892, Severity: 20, State: 1.
......

2019-03-20 16:38:49.19 Logon       Login succeeded for user <<User Name 1>>. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENT: 10.144.227.204]
```

As you can see the same user is first able to login without any problem and then the logon fails for some time and then start to work again! This goes on and off for some time and then start to work again.

We do have a logon trigger that uses APP_NAME() to check the application name and write to a log table if a certain condition are met. The user rights should be alright as it is able to insert records into the logging table. For this user that the error is occurring for there should not be any logging. The trigger is created with 'WITH EXECUTE AS SELF'.

On request here is the trigger code

```
CREATE   TRIGGER [tr_sasLogon]
ON ALL SERVER
WITH EXECUTE AS SELF
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
    IF
    (APP_NAME() like 'SOMETHING%') 
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO tkadmin.dbo.audit_login 
                (date, login, program_name) 
                    VALUES 
                (GETDATE(), ORIGINAL_LOGIN(),APP_NAME()) 
    END
END
GO
```

Anyone got some ideas what can be the issue causing this behavior?

Comment: "should be alright" - did you check? Disable the trigger, impersonate that login, and try to insert into the log table. And double-check the logic in the rest of the trigger, too. Anyway we can't possibly solve this problem as written - you've made some assumptions and haven't given us the details.

Comment: Hi, Could you add the trigger query text? You could start a profiler trace / extended event to monitor what launches when the user tries to login.

Comment: For example, your logon trigger could check for a number of connections for current login and do rollback if it is >= some number

Comment: Sorry for being little bit vague. I have myself created the trigger and I'm able to insert records into the table. Have I understood correct that when creating the trigger with execute as self then it is run with the privileges of the creator? The trigger is also working in the same database for some other users/applications so that was why I did say should be alright.

Comment: (Randi) The extended event was the next thing on my list of things to do. Any suggestion of what events should be good to follow?

Comment: Do you have another trigger on tkadmin.dbo.audit_login? Are login and program_name columns long enough to hold the login and app name values?

Comment: (sepupic) As the same user is connecting multiple times this sounds interesting. Can you please expand on why it will fail if the current login has a number of connections >= some number?

Comment: (EzLo) No we do not have any other trigger on the audit_login table. Both columns are varchar(128).

Comment: Add a `TRY ... CATCH` block, and have the catch block `RAISERROR ... WITH (LOG)` to write the error information into your windows log. This should give you more information to work with. Also note that `varchar(128)` is incorrect - these columns should match _sysname_, and so be `nvarchar(128)`.

Comment: I have now tried to catch this error with a TRY .... CATCH block around the code section of the trigger. I'm still getting the same error message in the log and not the re raised error message from the CATCH block! Seems like the error is occurring prior to the execution of the code block.